# Customizing URL in Jenkins

Tags: url, dns

I've created Jenkins for managing my project. I want to share these files with a few people. Problem is that URL is http://localhost:8080/ . How can I make it public for my co-workers (I want it public like [this side](http://ic2api.player.to:8080))? I know there is "Jenkins URL" setting in configuration, but when I'll put URL there the page doesn't exist. Any ideas how to do it? (I'm beginner with this stuff so could you explain it to me? thx)

I'm using W7 x64

Answer (score 6):

You need 2 things at first:

1. You need to have an **static external IP address**. Either your network admin or your ISP should provide you with one.
2. Once you have the IP, you need to register a DNS name, and point to that IP address.

**Alternatively,** if you cannot get a static external IP address, you can use a Dynamic DNS (DDNS) service, however you need to make sure your IP address is accessible externally

1. Find out your external IP address (probably in your router configuration).
2. Make sure your router and/or firewall allow external traffic to your Jenkins port (8080)
3. Register on some free DDNS server, such as http://www.noip.com/free

Comment: What do you mean by `register a DNS name, and point to that IP address`?  What do you point from.

Comment: [https://www.godaddy.com](https://www.godaddy.com) -> register/pay for DNS name. Once bought, configure it to point to public static IP address of your Jenkins server. Provided you don't have any firewall/router blocking your static IP address, other people around the world could now just type the DNS name and access your server

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to perform it.

in case  all are under same network they you can add your IP (with fashionate host name you like) in your co-workers system's  /etc/hosts file.. its simplest way.

```
<IP>  <HOST NAME>
```

Even if you dont want to use the "localhost", you can change it in config.xml.

you can resolve host name using DNS server also

Comment: What line do you `change it in config.xml` to use instead of localhost?