# How can I access my Jenkins in public system?

Tags: jenkins

I need to access my Jenkins form some public url so that I can access that from any other machine. 
Is there any way. I show an option I need my public ip and form that I can access it. but I don't know how can I do that. 
I'm beginner in Jenkins right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing URL in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208835/customizing-url-in-jenkins)

Comment: I tried those ways but couldn't succeed, and both answer are not yet verified or checked.

Comment: You need a domain that will point to ip of machine that has Jenkins installed. Good idea is to setup reverse proxy with HTTPS settings. For that you can use something like Apache or nginx. Remember about Atuhentication and Authorization if you Jenkins instance is publicly available.

Comment: @Cosaquee - I checked with https://www.noip.com which is accessing the public ip of my machine and change to some DNS host name. which DNS host name I've added in my jenkins configuration url i.e. http://xyz.ddns.com:8080 but no success though.